# Vim is highlights everything after EOL in yellow upon scrolling

Tags: highlight, color

My vimrc: http://ge0rges.com/vimrc 
My environment is: Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL on Windows 10.

[image: The issue]

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +vertsplit
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              -X11
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xim
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xpm
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2
-fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-8l5tlu/vim-8.0.1453=. -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed
-o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
-L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl
-lutil -lm
```

My problem is that when I open a file (here a .c file), everything after the last character of a line is highlighted in yellow. This has a weird behavior though because it doesn't happen on the first page (ie landing after opening a file) and it goes away if the scroll bar is on the line. In addition, if I scroll up or down with the mouse wheel, the yellow highlight comes back.

Edit: After investigation it seems to be the theme I am using that's causing the issue. Though this doesn't happen on other Ubuntu terminals, might be WSL's fault. After installing a different theme I notice that the same issue arises only with different colors.

Comment: Hello @Ge0rges, welcome to [vi.se]! Would you mind [edit]ing your question to (1) include the screenshot, vimrc, and test file in the question—shorten them, if necessary—and (2) break up the version output—it's all on one line at the moment?

Comment: In the meantime, I've seen a few questions like this before, but I can't find the exact ones I'm looking for

Comment: @DBenKnoble Yeah this comes up from time to time... Some of it in SO or Superuser.SE, I think none of them has a good answer to the problem... I guess it's most probably related to the terminal, but it's hard to get all the details needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble done. I have an issue with the terminal where it removes newlines, so not possible to fix sample file. Replaced the rest with images.

Comment: @Ge0rges I got the version info for you ;)

Comment: What happens if you remove `" mac italics support
let &t_ZH="\e[3m"
let &t_ZR="\e[23m"
`? This behavior is usually a term issue

Comment: @Ge0rges No idea whether it will help, but it could be due to the terminfo `bce` boolean capability. If it's set in the description of the terminal (the one reported by `$ infocmp -x $TERM`), maybe Vim sets the terminal option `t_ut` with the value `y`, and in that case it clears the screen with the current background color. Try to reset the option with `set t_ut=` or `if &term =~# '-256color$'|set t_ut=|endif`. See also `:h t_ut` and `man 5 terminfo`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that did not fix it.

Comment: @user938271 running `set t_ut=` didn't fix it. And the other command gave an error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`&' `

Comment: All, please view edit. It seems that not using my color scheme avoids the issue though I am still interested in a fix.

Comment: @Ge0rges The commands are supposed to be entered in vim command mode (`:`), not in bash shell.

Comment: @user938271 your solution `set t_ut` works but is not persistent. Feel free to answer this question and get some karma

Comment: This is not an answer but I was unable to leave a comment as I do not have 50 points. I am having the same issue. I noticed that the color is tied to the color of the first colorbox within the Properties/Colors tab.
I right click on the bar. Click on properties. Then select the Colors tab.
The first color box is the color for the vimbackground for sections that have been scrolled through.
Hope this can provide further guidance in arriving at an answer.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIH8u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIH8u.png)
I now realized a potential solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `autocmd VimEnter * set t_ut=` to your vimrc file.